# Need help in XSLT 2.0 to replace ambersand & with &amp;

Tags: java, xml, xslt-2.0

I want to replace `&` with `&amp;` using XSLT2.0. Please advise.
For Eg: input `<description>Rock&Roll</description>`

the expected output is: 
`<description>Rock&amp;Roll</description>`

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: `&` in your XML means it's not well-formed.  Fix that problem ***before*** calling XSLT.  See duplicate link for options.

Answer (score 0):

A file containing

```
<description>Rock&Roll</description>
```

is not well-formed XML.
The ampersand has to be escaped beforehand.
See [WikiPedia for the definition of a well-formed XML document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_document).